# Cannot open database "dbTest" requested by the login. The login failed. windows service

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-services, database-backups

I created a Windows service that takes a SQL Server database backup on the fix time interval. The Windows service works perfectly in debug mode but when it was installed its keep running but not creating `.bak` file.

I checked log file and found

> Cannot open database "dbTest" requested by the login. The login failed.

I used Windows authentication for the connection.

Here is my code snippet

```
public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
{
    Timer _timer = new Timer();

    public Service1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        this.WriteToFile("Simple Service started {0}");
        // _timer = new Timer(10 * 60 * 1000); // every 10 minutes
        _timer = new Timer(60000); // every 10 minutes
        _timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);
        _timer.Start(); // <- important

    }

    private void timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.WriteToFile("ScheduleBackupService: Method Call");
        this.ScheduleBackupService();
    }

    public void ScheduleBackupService()
    {
        string backupPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BackupFile"];
        this.WriteToFile("Backup Path {0}" + backupPath);
        string ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"];
        this.WriteToFile("Connection String {0}" + ConnectionString);
        string DbList = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["dbList"];
        this.WriteToFile("Connection String {0}" + DbList);
        string[] words = DbList.Split(',');
        foreach (string word in words)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine("WORD: " + word);
            CreateBackFile(backupPath, word, ConnectionString);
        }


    }
    internal static string CreateDirectory(string path)
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(path))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
        }
        return path;
    }
    public string GetDirectoryPath()
    {

        string filePath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "SqlDataBaseBackup");

        if (!Directory.Exists(filePath))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(filePath);
        }
        return filePath;

    }

    public void CreateBackFile(string path, string dbName, string ConnectionString)
    {
        try
        {
            string name = dbName;            
            name = name + ".bak";
            string backupPath = @"BACKUP DATABASE " + dbName + " TO DISK = N'" + path + @"\" + name + @"'";
            this.WriteToFile("backup Path Query" + backupPath);
            string svr = ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(svr);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(backupPath, con);
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                this.WriteToFile("BackUp Create Successfully {0}" + dbName);                
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                WriteToFile("Service Error Exception CreateBackFile: {0} " + ex.Message);
                this.WriteToFile("Service Error Exception CreateBackFile" + ex.StackTrace);                
            }

            finally
            {
                if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    con.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            this.WriteToFile("Service Error Exception : {0} " + ex.Message);
            this.WriteToFile("Service Error Exception  : {0}" + ex.StackTrace);
            //Stop the Windows Service.
            using (System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController serviceController = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController("Service1"))
            {
                serviceController.Stop();
            }
        }

    }

    private void CreateZipFile(string path, string dbName)
    {
        //to store the value of folderapth   
        string FolderPathToZip = path;
        //To create unique file name with date and time with nanoseconds.  

        string ZbackupPath = CreateDirectory(GetDirectoryPath() + "\\BackupZip\\");
        string ZipFileName = ZbackupPath + dbName + ".zip";
        try
        {
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(ZipFileName))
                System.IO.File.Delete(ZipFileName);
            ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(FolderPathToZip, ZipFileName);
            Array.ForEach(Directory.GetFiles(path), File.Delete);
            this.WriteToFile("File Copy  Successfully {0} this" + path);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //If system throw any exception message box will display "SOME ERROR"  
            // Notification(ex.Message);
        }

    }

    public void WriteToFile(string text)
    {
        string path = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LogFile"];
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(path, true))
        {
            writer.WriteLine(string.Format(text, DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt")));
            writer.Close();
        }
    }
    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        this.WriteToFile("Simple Service stopped {0}");        
    }
}
```

Here is my connection string saved in `app.config`:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key ="Mode" value ="Interval"/>        
    <add key ="ConnectionString" value ="Data Source=DESKTOP-2TGRDDE;Initial Catalog=dbTest;Integrated Security=True"/>    
    <add key ="dbList" value ="dbBackUpFtp"/>
    <add key ="LogFile" value ="D:\\Backup\\ServiceLog.txt"/>
    <add key ="BackupFile" value ="D:\\Backup\\"/>
    <add key ="IntervalMinutes" value ="1"/>
    <add key ="ScheduledTime" value ="16:02"/>
  </appSettings>
```

and project installer content in initialization

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{
    this.serviceProcessInstaller1 = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceProcessInstaller();
    this.serviceInstaller1 = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceInstaller();
    // 
    // serviceProcessInstaller1
    // 
    this.serviceProcessInstaller1.Account = System.ServiceProcess.ServiceAccount.LocalSystem;
    this.serviceProcessInstaller1.Password = null;
    this.serviceProcessInstaller1.Username = null;
    // 
    // serviceInstaller1
    // 

    this.serviceInstaller1.Description = "BackUp Service";
    this.serviceInstaller1.DisplayName = "BackUpService.Demo";
    this.serviceInstaller1.ServiceName = "Service1";
    // 
    // ProjectInstaller
    // 
    this.Installers.AddRange(new System.Configuration.Install.Installer[] {
    this.serviceProcessInstaller1,
    this.serviceInstaller1});

}
```

Sorry, I uploaded all code as did lots of r&d but failed.

Is any changes needed to code section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the service account is `LocalSystem`, that account needs connect permissions to the `dbTest` database along with permissions to backup the db. Assuming the service and SQL Server are running on the same machine, the script to assign minimum permissions to backup the database is:

```
USE dbTest;
CREATE USER [NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM];
ALTER ROLE db_backupoperator
    ADD MEMBER [NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM];
```